# how to delete the cookies in jsp/java

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

This my code for setting new cookie

```
Cookie citizen = new Cookie("citizen",email);
citizen.setMaxAge(3600);
response.addCookie(citizen);
```

now i'm using this code for destroying the cookie

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].getName().equals("citizen")) {
             cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
}
}
```

But, i'm still getting cookie value. Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: Do you mean that in the next request the client still sends the cookie?

Comment: no, i just found the above code and used it. but, it is not working.

Comment: How is it "not working"? Do you mean that in the next request the client still sends the cookie? If not, what happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: It works for me. Created a page which if it gets the parameter "add" sets the cookie and if it gets the parameter "delete" it deletes the cookie (as your code above). The request after the delete contains no cookie (using Safari). Can you log what your send and gets?

Comment: have you checked if the String is matched correctly? Maybe your if-statement doesnt fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below link might help you..

[How can delete information from cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332258/how-can-delete-information-from-cookies)

Good Luck!!!

Let me know incase of any further queries...

Answer (score 2):

I was having a problem similar to this, where the cookie retained the value even after setting max age to 0 and the value to "".

I used firefox to look at the cookie attributes to help debug.  When logging in, the servlet called my cookie class to set the cookie, and the cookie path was "/javawork/".  When logging out, the JSP page called the same cookie class to "delete" the cookie by setting the max age to 0.  But the JSP page was in a sub folder in the web app, so the when I created a cookie of the same name with max age of 0, it created a new cookie with the path "/javawork/test_login/".

So that "new" cookie immediately expired, but the original one still existed.  In my delete cookie function I needed to set the path of the "new" cookie to be "/javawork/", and when I set the max age to 0 and added it, it updated the original cookie and let me properly log out.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
 cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
 //add this line
 cookies[i].setPath("/");
 response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The option correct will be

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("citizen", "citizen");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setValue("");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

if you try to get the cookie from request for next add it to response with setMaxAge(0), you could see that the cookie doesn't been removed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me -

```
Cookie UIDCookie = new Cookie(COOKIE_KEY, "");
UIDCookie.setMaxAge(0);
UIDCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(qptUIDCookie);
```

Comment: I think you mean UIDCookie instead qptUIDCookie ))

Answer (score 0):

We can delete a cookie by setting max age as zero.
For example:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
cookies[0].setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookies[0]);
```

Here we delete only the first cookie

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332258/how-can-delete-information-from-cookies/49837629#49837629